# Other than a run out, how can a player be dismissed when a run is scored?

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

Other than a run out, is there a way in cricket where a player is but the team gets a run? I'm asking this as I once saw "W+1" on a scoresheet and wondered how that was possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've noted, the most common way for this to occur is a run out while attempting a second (or later) run, but there are a number of other ways:

- A batsman being out stumped or hit wicket from a [wide ball](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-25-wide-ball/) - see clause 16. For a recent example of a stumping from a wide, see [India vs Bangladesh in the 2016 World T20](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/match/951353.html?innings=2;view=commentary):

  > 9.3 Raina to Sabbir Rahman, 1 wide, OUT, oooh, Dhoni goes up for a stumping and he is very quick with those.
- A batsman being out [handled the ball](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-33-handled-the-ball/), [hit the ball twice](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-34-hit-the-ball-twice/) or [obstructing the field](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-37-obstructing-the-field/) from a [no ball](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-24-no-ball/) - see clause 24.
- A batsman being out hit the ball twice or obstructing the field after having completed a run. (Hit the ball twice is even more unlikely than most of these as it cannot happen after a fielder touches the ball, but I think it could happen in some very convoluted circumstances).

Comment: Thanks, Ill look out for these happenings in the future. can only remember one, which is the incident with ben stokes but seeing as they hadn't run it was just a wicket